# Discrod.js стандартные emoji

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord-api

Я использую discrod.js и пытаюсь добавить реакцию к сообщению программно. Но проблема в том, что стандартные emoji не работают. Их имена, которые используются в дискорде, не работают. В документации написано, что их можно использовать просто вставив их юникод.
Например я хочу вставить галочку, в дискорде этот символ называется `:white_check_mark:`. Я пытаюсь выполнить функцию `message.react(':white_check_mark:')` - не работает, ошибка `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Emoji`. Далее я пробую сделать так: `message.react('\u{2705}')` - работает, но при попытке выполнить `message.reaction.get('\u{2705}')` - ничего не работает. Далее я попытался использовать `\:white_check_mark:` - работает абсолютно так же, как и с юникодом. После этого я решил поискать эти emoji, так как в документации написано, что такая возможность есть. Выполняю `const emoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'white_check_mark');` и получаю 'undefined'. Так же я пробовал искать юникод и другие вариации. А если я пытаюсь найти кастомные emoji, то он находит объект `GuildEmoji`.

Я использую исходный код этого бота https://github.com/ansonfoong/Discord-Ticket-Bot/blob/master/ticketbot-reaction.js. (У автора данного кода используются кастомные emoji :ticketreact: и :checkreact: их то я и хочу заменить.) Данный код написан на старом API поэтому для работоспособности некоторые функции нужно переделать.

Comment: С Discord не работаю, так что на уровне предположения: в приведенном вами примере после имени указан некий id (скорее всего id пака с эмодзи), который скорее всего характерен и для эмодзи по умолчанию. Попробуйте поискать нужный вам код так: `const emoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => (emoji.name || "").includes('white_check_mark'));`

Comment: Возможно, используемая библиотека не выполянет следующее условие: `The emoji must be URL Encoded or the request will fail with 10014: Unknown Emoji` Так что ваш код нужно поправить следующим образом: `message.react(encodeURIComponent(':white_check_mark:'))`. Аналогично для get: `message.reaction.get(encodeURIComponent(':white_check_mark:'))`

Comment: Опять же, если `:white_check_mark:` не требует после себя идентификатора

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, в том то и дело, что `: white_check_mark: ` не имеет идентификатора. Точнее, он есть, но дискорд его не воспринимает и имеет он буквенно-числовой набор, а не просто числа. Проблему я решил, путем добавления этих же эмодзи только в качестве кастомных.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы добавить реакцию стандартным эмоджи на сообщение, нужно просто его написать в текстовом варианте `msg.react("✅")` или любые другие эмоджи.
Можно будет их добавить в качестве констант и использовать эти константы  `const white_check_mark = "✅" msg.react(white_check_mark)`